# location.reload() not working after jQuery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this code, none of the animations happen - it skips straight to the `location.reload()`. However, if I remove `location.reload()`, the animations work fine.

How can I have both?

```
$( "#welcome" ).animate({
    opacity: 0,
}, 100, function() {
})
$( "#signup_link" ).animate({
    opacity: 0,
}, 200, function() {
})
$( "#forgotten" ).animate({
    opacity: 0,
}, 200, function() {
})

$('.login-container').animate({ opacity: 0, top: "-100px" }, 'fast').delay(3000);

location.reload();
```

Comment: Wonder why? Why do you reload the page for no apparent reason.

Comment: It's the response for an AJAX request. I'm developing a Chrome extension and this is the login.

Comment: If you know ajax, you probably know it's async. So are the animations, hence the callback functions

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this: I'm assuming you want the animations and reload to fire as you have them sitting in your original post. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pv4RV/2/

note: I commented out the 'reload' part as that will then just generate a loop on the page.

```
$.when(
    function(){
            $( "#welcome" ).animate({opacity: 0,}, 100, function() {});
            $( "#signup_link" ).animate({opacity: 0,}, 200, function() {});
            $( "#forgotten" ).animate({opacity: 0,}, 200, function() {});
    }()
).then(
    $('.login-container').animate({ opacity: 0, top: "-100px" }, 'fast').delay(3000)
).then( 
    location.reload() 
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I gave it a shot (with commas after lines 2 and 3) but it's not doing anything (no animation, no errors).

Comment: It gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on line 3.